# How to set trace name in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I am using this class to draw a trace, I've got 2 lines to trace, but I cannot display name of each line, how to?

```
class Plot2D():
    def __init__(self):
        self.traces = dict()

        #QtGui.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem('raster')
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication([])
        #mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        #mw.resize(800,800)

        self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Detecting cluck")
        self.win.resize(1000,600)
        self.win.setWindowTitle('Detecting')
        # Enable antialiasing for prettier plots
        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

        self.canvas = self.win.addPlot(title="改装车检测")
        self.canvas.setYRange(0, 1)

    def start(self):
        if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
            QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()

    def trace(self,name,dataset_x,dataset_y,sColor):
        if name in self.traces:
            self.traces[name].setData(dataset_x,dataset_y)
        else:
            self.traces[name] = self.canvas.plot(
                pen=pg.mkPen(sColor, width=3), name="car")
```

what I got:

what I got

[image]

what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `addLegend()`, in addition to establishing a name in the plot:

```
import sys
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

class Plot2D():
    def __init__(self):
        self.traces = dict()

        self.app = QtGui.QApplication([])

        self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Detecting")
        self.win.resize(1000,600)
        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

        self.canvas = self.win.addPlot(title="改装车检测")
        self.canvas.addLegend()
        self.canvas.setYRange(0, 1)

    def start(self):
        if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
            QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()

    def trace(self,name,dataset_x,dataset_y,sColor):
        if name in self.traces:
            self.traces[name].setData(dataset_x,dataset_y)
        else:
            self.traces[name] = self.canvas.plot(dataset_x, dataset_y,
                pen=pg.mkPen(sColor, width=3), name=name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Plot2D()
    p.trace("name1", range(100), 0.5 + np.random.normal(size=100, scale=0.1), 'r')
    p.trace("name2", range(100), 0.5 + np.random.normal(size=100, scale=0.1), 'w')
    p.start()
```

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to change the font size you can use HTML

```
self.traces[name] = self.canvas.plot(dataset_x, dataset_y,
    pen=pg.mkPen(sColor, width=3), name='''<font size="15">{}</font>'''.format(name))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you tell me how to change the font size of legend?

Comment: @Simon let me find out if you can change the font of the legend, on the other hand if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.